# UIImage only for the chosen applicationActivities, but NSString for all applicationActivities

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uiactivityviewcontroller, uiactivity

I'm using UIActivityViewController for share NSString and UIImage, but I don't want to share the UIImage with iMessage & e-mail.

How can I create such a custom UIActivity for UIImage and leave NSString for all?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your UIActivityViewController, you pass along an array of activity items.

And the objects you pass along in that array can be objects that adopt the [UIActivityItemSource protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIActivityItemSource).

And if you send along a UIImage, why not create a "`ImageItemProvider`" object and then implement your own ["`activityViewController:itemForActivityType:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityItemSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIActivityItemSource/activityViewController%3aitemForActivityType%3a) method that returns "`nil`" if you don't want to share the image via iMessage or email.

E.G.:

```
//- Returns the data object to be acted upon. (required)
- (id)activityViewController:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController itemForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
        return nil;
    }

    if ([activityType isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMessage]) {
        return nil;
    }

    return [UIImage imageNamed:@"the image you wanted returned"];
}
```

I'm basing this answer on [the code I found in this tutorial](http://www.absoluteripple.com/1/post/2013/05/customising-the-activity-view-controller.html).

Comment: It is some idea, but UIImage is dynamic (capture view), so if I create a new object the UIActivityViewController will be loading too long. I think, that the best way is simply code in main view, but I don't now how :(

Comment: If generating the thing to be shared can take a while, you might want to look into using UIActivityItemProvider.